# Sort a Map<Int, Int> by value then by key

Tags: sorting, dictionary, kotlin

I've got a map of values where the key is a digit and the value is the number of the occurrences of the digit in a string

example :

```
6644241333431
{6:2,4:4,2:1,3:4,1:2}
```

I would like to get the digit with the most occurrences, if two numbers are equals then get the smaller one.
I feel like it could be done with ".sortedBy{ (key, value) -> ... }" or even "compareBy{ it.first }.thenBy{it.second}".

Comment: I was just try to explain how the map was like, I might have used the wrong character to trap my digits sorry :/ Yes, exactly as you said

Comment: Okay, so why do you want to sort? You can simply iterate the entries can get the maximum as you go. This will be linear time, and faster than sorting

Comment: Add first, I implemented the method with the way I know (some "if" and loops) like everytime I code. But I'm trying to do everything different and "better" because I realised then I'm not getting better so I was wondering if there was a better way to get the digits that had the most occurrences (I was looking for putting it in the .key[0] spot). But you're right I guess, it's heavier on hardware :/ so not very useful

Comment: Wait, so you don't really need sorting, but only the maximum value?

Comment: yes but I already knew how to get maximum value, I was looking for knowing more about sorting too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this almost the way you described:

```kotlin
map.entries
    .sortedWith(compareByDescending<Map.Entry<Int, Int>> { it.value }.thenByDescending { it.key })
```

It returns a list, not a map. You can convert it back to map if you need.

If you only need a single, maximum value, then sorting is really not necessary and you can find it in a similar way as above:

```kotlin
map.maxOfWith(compareBy<Map.Entry<Int, Int>> { it.value }.thenBy { it.key }) { it }
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for the fast answer ! I should have searched more about what the entries was. I had to change the "thenBy" so it could do what I was looking for but thank you so much ! Have a nice day
map.entries.sortedWith(compareByDescending<Map.Entry<Int, Int>> { it.value }.thenBy { it.key })

Comment: See also the updated answer. If you only need the maximum value then it makes more sense to use `maxOfWih()` instead.